# How to update just one key of python's nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I run into a strange behavior of Python nested dictionaries. I want to update key `var_set` in nested dictionary when upper key is `global`. But it updates all `var_set` recursively even when upper key is `foo` and `bar`.

```
g = 'global'
s = set()
space = {g:
         {'parent': 'None', 'var_set': s, 'child_dict': {}
          }
         }

def create(child, parent, space):
    if parent in space.keys():
        space[parent]['child_dict'][child] = {
            'parent': parent, 'var_set': s, 'child_dict': {}}
    else:
        create(child, parent, space[g]['child_dict'])

def adding(parent, var, space):
    for (k, v) in space.items():
        if k == parent:
            v['var_set'].add(var)

create('foo', 'global', space)
create('bar', 'foo', space)
print(space)
adding(g, 'a', space)
print(space)
```

returns:

```py
{'global': {'parent': 'None', 'var_set': set(), 'child_dict': {'foo': {'parent': 'global',
                                                                       'var_set': set(), 'child_dict': {'bar': {'parent': 'foo', 'var_set': set(), 'child_dict': {}}}}}}}
{'global': {'parent': 'None', 'var_set': {'a'}, 'child_dict': {'foo': {'parent': 'global',
                                                                       'var_set': {'a'}, 'child_dict': {'bar': {'parent': 'foo', 'var_set': {'a'}, 'child_dict': {}}}}}}}
```

Why all `var_set` updated recursively? I need just first one to be updated.

Well, let's copy the first result with empty sets and call `adding` against it too:

```
create('foo', 'global', space)
create('bar', 'foo', space)

lst = {'global': {'parent': 'None', 'var_set': set(), 'child_dict': {'foo': {'parent': 'global',
                                                                             'var_set': set(), 'child_dict': {'bar': {'parent': 'foo', 'var_set': set(), 'child_dict': {}}}}}}}

print(lst == space)
adding(g, 'a', lst)
adding(g, 'a', space)
print(lst)
print(space)
```

It returns:

```
True
{'global': {'parent': 'None', 'var_set': {'a'}, 'child_dict': {'foo': {'parent': 'global',
 'var_set': set(), 'child_dict': {'bar': {'parent': 'foo', 'var_set': set(), 'child_dict': {}}}}}}}
{'global': {'parent': 'None', 'var_set': {'a'}, 'child_dict': {'foo': {'parent': 'global',
                                                                       'var_set': {'a'}, 'child_dict': {'bar': {'parent': 'foo', 'var_set': {'a'}, 'child_dict': {}}}}}}}
```

They are equal and gives different results. Why such divergence? How to make it update just `global`'s `var_set` and ignore `foo`'s and `bar`'s ones?

**Update:**

The problem is in declaring empty set globally for `var_sets`. They link to one object. Changing it once will change it for `var_set`s.

Comment: Why do you create only one set and use it in every dictionary? Just move `s = set()` and `'var_set' : s` to `'var_set' : set()` (also I'd recommend reading [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) before sharing your code with other people).

Comment: It should be supported up to 20 levels of nesting (you are at 1/3 of this limit), but it becomes illegible and thus buggy much quicker... consider using `pprint` to make it more readable a la JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in declaring empty set globally for var_sets. They link to one object. Changing it once will change it for every var_sets.

Thanks to @jonrsharpe